# GAQL running on an MCC doesn't show a campaign

Tags: google-ads-api, google-ads-script

I've tried to run this GAQL on an MCC, but didn't get any rows.

ads-script:

```
campaignIds query =SELECT customer.id, campaign.resource_name, campaign.name FROM campaign WHERE campaign.id IN ("123456");
_rowsToMap(accountToCampaignsMap, AdsApp.report(query, REPORTING_OPTIONS));
    }

    function _rowsToMap(map, response) {
      rows = response.rows();
      while (rows.hasNext()) {
        var row = rows.next();
        Logger.log(JSON.stringify(row));
...
}
```

Even though I see it in the UI under this MCC

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because you don't have campaigns on this account, but in managed accounts you do. Try first get list of managed accounts then query every one, lige this:

```js
const query = 'selsct ... from ...'
const accounts = AdsManagerApp.accounts().get()
const campaignsData = []
while (accounts.hasNext()) {
    var account = accounts.next();
    AdsManagerApp.select(account)
    const search = AdsApp.search(query)
    while (search.hasNext()) {
        const searchRow = search.next();
        campaignsData.push({
            accountName: account.getName(),
            accointId: account.getCustomerId(),
            ...,
        })
    }
}
```